# Connect Four game without diagonals check or validation

Tags: java, connect-four

This is a simple implementation of Connect four in Java. It is working correctly so far.
 What I haven't done yet are the diagonals check and input validation.

```
package game;

import java.util.Scanner;
//TODO check for diagonals, input validation

public class Game {
    private char[][] gameBoard;
    private State gameState;
    private Turn turn;
    private int[] possiblePositions;
    private static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 6;
    private static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 7;

    enum Turn {
        PLAYER_ONE, PLAYER_TWO
    }

    enum State {
        PLAYER_1_WIN, PLAYER_2_WIN, RUNNING
    }

    public Game() {
        gameBoard = new char[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_HEIGHT; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_WIDTH; col++) {
                gameBoard[row][col] = '□';
            }
        }
        turn = Turn.PLAYER_ONE;
        gameState = State.RUNNING;
        possiblePositions = new int[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    }

    public void playerMove(int column) {
        switch (turn) {
        case PLAYER_ONE:
            gameBoard[possiblePositions[column]][column] = '■';
            turn = Turn.PLAYER_TWO;
            break;
        case PLAYER_TWO:
            gameBoard[possiblePositions[column]][column] = '⊠';
            turn = Turn.PLAYER_ONE;
            break;
        }
        possiblePositions[column]--;
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5 6");
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_HEIGHT; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_WIDTH; col++) {
                System.out.print(gameBoard[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void checkRowAndCol() {
        int chainLength = 1;
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_HEIGHT - 1; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_WIDTH - 1; col++) {
                if (gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col + 1] && gameBoard[row][col] != '□') {
                    ++chainLength;
                    if (chainLength == 4) {
                        switch (gameBoard[row][col]) {
                        case '■':
                            gameState = State.PLAYER_1_WIN;
                            break;
                        case '⊠':
                            gameState = State.PLAYER_2_WIN;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    chainLength = 1;
                }
            }
            chainLength = 1;
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_WIDTH - 1; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_HEIGHT - 1; row++) {
                if (gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row + 1][col] && gameBoard[row][col] != '□') {
                    ++chainLength;
                    if (chainLength == 4) {
                        switch (gameBoard[row][col]) {
                        case '■':
                            gameState = State.PLAYER_1_WIN;
                            break;
                        case '⊠':
                            gameState = State.PLAYER_2_WIN;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    chainLength = 1;
                }
            }
            chainLength = 1;
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        printBoard();
        while (gameState == State.RUNNING) {
            playerMove(reader.nextInt());
            checkRowAndCol();
            printBoard();
        }
        System.out.println(gameState);
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Magic values

The implementation is mostly fine, except for the widespread magic values that would be better as constants, for example:

```
private static final char SYMBOL_EMPTY = '□';
private static final char SYMBOL_PLAYER1 = '■';
private static final char SYMBOL_PLAYER2 = '⊠';
```

Similarly, instead of initializing `possiblePositions` with `new int[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 }`, it would be better to derive the correct value from the `BOARD_WIDTH` and `BOARD_HEIGHT` constants.

#### Code duplication

This snippet is duplicated in `checkRowAndCol`:

> ```
> if (chainLength == 4) {
>     switch (gameBoard[row][col]) {
>         case '■':
>             gameState = State.PLAYER_1_WIN;
>             break;
>         case '⊠':
>             gameState = State.PLAYER_2_WIN;
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

It would be better to move this to a helper method.

#### Unnecessary execution

When a player wins,
you could return immediately from `checkRowAndCol`,
no need to continue checking all rows and columns.

The helper method I mentioned in the previous section could return a `boolean`,
with a `true` value if there is a winner.
When the returned value is `true`,
the caller in `checkRowAndCol` could return immediately.

#### Code organization

Instead of `checkRowAndCol`, it would be better to separate to `checkRow` and `checkCol` methods.
You could still have a `checkRowAndCol` method that calls the other two,
but there's no reason for these two independent aspects to be implemented in the same method.